# How to implement color correction?

Tags: android, colors, color-blindness

How can I implement Color Correction setting in my app?

**[Color Correction]**
[image]

I want to use these setting turn on/off/change through my application. I have searched on internet but not get any help. I have a launcher app, I want to use color correction in it. I have also looked on GitHub, but it didn't help.

Comment: You could do it with [OpenCV](https://opencv.org/platforms/android/)

Comment: Is there an easy way?

Comment: Note: you should not give user such "corrections". These settings are just for developers, to make visible how colour blind user will see your app. These options will not help (directly) in any case colour blind, and they will worsen the experience of users.

Comment: Yes, I agree. And I gonna do the same thing. But I don't know how to do it. Looks like no help coming.

Answer (score 0):

Well there are no color filters or anything else similar to implement this function. My advice would be to describe your own colors in `colors.xml` file with a prefix for setting, and then to change color programatically. You can find a little help her: https://medium.com/@appsogreat/how-to-make-your-app-colorblind-friendly-resources-and-experience-sharing-b46615c5a007

Comment: Is there an easy way?

Comment: Have you tried this library: https://github.com/skratchdot/color-blind ?

Comment: Thanks but, It is not an android library.

Comment: Oh sorry I used wrong link, try to analyze this code https://github.com/Drahflow/colorblind

Comment: It is for the camera only. And 6 years old.